# Modify table by squashing rows by truncated hour

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-11, sum

I have a table **ledger** which represents the ledger book.

```
            date            | user_id | usd_value | eur_value 
----------------------------+---------+-----------+-----------
 2020-01-13 19:00:10.877+03 |       1 |        10 |         0
 2020-01-13 19:10:15.4+03   |       1 |        30 |         0
 2020-01-13 19:44:40.187+03 |       1 |         0 |        40
 2020-01-13 19:45:06.935+03 |       2 |        15 |         0
 2020-01-13 19:46:22.38+03  |       1 |        40 |         0
 2020-01-13 19:50:43.176+03 |       2 |         0 |        15
 2020-01-13 20:08:58.47+03  |       1 |        55 |         0
```

This table is very big, so I want to reduce count of rows.

I am trying to determine the best way to accomplish task: **how can I modify origin (by deleting and updating rows) table to get following rows**:

```
            date            | user_id | usd_value | eur_value 
----------------------------+---------+-----------+-----------
 2020-01-13 19:00:10.877+03 |       1 |        80 |        40
 2020-01-13 19:45:06.935+03 |       2 |        15 |        15
 2020-01-13 20:08:58.47+03  |       1 |        55 |         0
```

This table is result of query:

```
SELECT min(date) as date, user_id, sum(usd_value) as usd_value, sum(eur_value) as eur_value
from ledger
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', date), user_id
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: General SQL queries are better asked on Stack Overflow; DBA.SE is more specialized, intended for server configuration, optimization, business intelligence, and advanced querying.  Have you searched on Stack Overflow for `UPDATE` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: How big is "very big"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any foreign keys referencing that table (i.e. "incoming" foreign keys), you could do something like this:

```
-- save the squashed data into a temporary table
create temp table new_data as 
SELECT min(date) as date, user_id, sum(usd_value) as usd_value, sum(eur_value) as eur_value
from ledger
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', date), user_id;

-- get rid of all the old rows
truncate table ledger;

-- then insert the saved data back into the table
insert into ledger (date, user_id, usd_value, eur_value)
select date, user_id, usd_value, eur_value
from new_data;
```

---

If you want to do that for just one year (or any other arbitrary time period), you need to replace the `truncate` part with an appropriate `delete` statement and change the query that creates the temp table to only the desired year (or time period).

e.g. to squash yesterday's rows:

```
create temp table new_data as 
SELECT min(date) as date, user_id, sum(usd_value) as usd_value, sum(eur_value) as eur_value
from ledger
-- only for yesterday
where date >= current_date - 1
  and date < current_date
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', date), user_id;

delete from ledger
where date >= current_date - 1
  and date < current_date

insert into ledger (date, user_id, usd_value, eur_value)
select date, user_id, usd_value, eur_value
from new_data;
```

Comment: Thank's for answer! `user_id` is foreign key.

Comment: @Andrei: I assume it's _referencing_  another table. Not being _referenced_ from another table.